# Is signalr 3.0 beta available yet for 2015?

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core

Would like to port Signalr code into vnext project but I do not see the references for SignalR 3.x.

Comment: You could expect SignalR 3 around Q3 2016: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Roadmap

Comment: I'm waiting for the SignalR .NET Client code to be available for a project - In this case dnxcore50 is the aim for a specific part of the application and SignalR client is the only part preventing it right now, luckily it's not urgent

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to reference the package in your `project.json` file, like so:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Server": "3.0.0-*"
 }
```

A vNext SignalR sample: https://github.com/aspnet/BugTracker

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Kiran!

Comment: The sample is using SignalR 2!