# signalr and .net 5

Tags: signalr, asp.net-core

I'm trying to do the following but I believe it is wrong.  I'm trying to update counters on a dashboard using signalr.  I tried following the post here [Is signalr 3.0 beta available yet for 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26982658/is-signalr-3-0-beta-available-yet-for-2015)

```
$(function () {

    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    var dashboardHub = $.connection.dashboardcounts;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        dashboardHub.invoke('UpdateCounters');

    });

    dashboardHub.on('updatedCounters'), function (data) {

        if (data.length > 0) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $.each(data, function () {
                $("#" + this.id).text(this.count)
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax issue. It should read:

```
    dashboardHub.on('updatedCounters', function (data) {
```